# Show a moving Image on screen

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want an Background image and another image that is moving down over the background image and when it reaches at bottom then it stops there? How can I do this.
"It can be same as street image over which leaves are falling"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom create a layout and in that layout add an imageview(keep your image as a background image for this image view) and apply translate animation on the layout. In the XML make the layout invisible and in your code make it visible

You should have this code in ur XML.  set this layout at the bottom and change the height , width and visibility according to ur need. Remember ur activity shd implement animationListner

```
       <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="220dip"
 android:orientation="vertical"

 android:layout_marginTop="480dip"

 >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview" 
   android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
   android:visibility="invisible" 
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
   android:background="@drawable/stoke1">
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The java code is like this

```
         Animation movement5; 
  layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);


 movement5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.layout.animation_test5);
    movement5.reset();
        movement5.setfillafter(true)
    movement5.setAnimationListener(this);
         layout3.startAnimation(movement5);
```

animation_test5.xml .

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="-300%"
  android:toYDelta="100%" android:duration="3000" android:zAdjustment="normal" />
```

Comment: @Geetanjali, I edited my answer. Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: where to put this animation_test5.xml file?

Comment: @Raghu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1725/discussion-between-geetanjali-and-raghu)

Comment: @Raghu how can i apply fade in/fade out effect to the next image in that queue?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution for a normal interface situation is to put the stuff you want to move into a view and do a view animation. Specifically a create and start a new translation animation on the view.

This is the technique commonly used to animate interface objects on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    mImage=act.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("imag­ename", "drawable", "packagename"));

        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

MOdify the code surely it will do your Job

Comment: But I don't wanna use gestures in it

Comment: ya i knw, but you can do that also write invalidate on construction check the position mPOsx & again Recall invalidate still it reaches bottom

Comment: where is the ScaleGestureDetector class

Comment: hey I have deleted the code in onTouchEvent so its showing error....Is there any other way to do this withour gestures